# Comparing the values inside a list with dictionary values inside the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary inside a list :

```
list1 = [{'Value': 'John','Key': 'Name'},{'Value':'17','Key': 'Number'}]
```

And i have a list:

```
list2 = ['Name','Number']
```

How to check the values inside **list2** are present in the **list1**. 
If present i need to list the the **Value**.

Eg: If Name is present , print "**John**"

Answer (score 1):

Please also read the comments:

```
for i in list2: #iterate through list2
        for j in list1: #iterate through list of dictinaries
            if i in j.values(): #if value of list2 present in the values of a dict then proceed
                print(j['Value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop. Note I use `set` for `list2` to enable O(1) lookup within your loop.

```
list1 = [{'Value': 'John','Key': 'Name'},{'Value':'17','Key': 'Number'}]

list2 = {'Name', 'Number'}

for item in list1:
    if item['Key'] in list2:
        print(item['Value'])

# John
# 17
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my one-line style suggestions easily readable IMHO.

1. First solution with result sorted in the same order as `list1`:

   ```
   list1 = [{'Value': 'John','Key': 'Name'},{'Value':'17','Key': 'Number'}]
   list2 = ['Name','Number']

   values = [x['Value'] for x in list1 if x['Key'] in list2]

   print(values)
   # ['John', '17']
   ```
2. Second solution with result sorted in the same order as `list2`:

   ```
   list1 = [{'Value': 'John','Key': 'Name'}, {'Value':'17','Key': 'Number'}]
   list2 = ['Number', 'Name']

   values = [x['Value'] for v in list2 for x in list1 if x['Key'] == v]

   print(values)
   # ['17', 'John']
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would transform your `list1` into its destiny: a dictionary.

```
dict1 = {d['Key']: d['Value'] for d in list1}
```

Then you can simply loop over `list2` and print the value if the key is there:

```
for key in list2:
    if key in dict1:
        print(dict1[key])
```

This prints:

```
John
17
```